# Why i only need to provide "console.log" to my catch promise method to log error?

Tags: javascript, function, es6-promise, first-class-functions

I have a simple promise, but I wonder why in my catch method I only need to pass "console.log" and it will automatically log that error if it happens?
[image]

Does it have something to do with the fact that catch automatically  gives us an error object or is it something else?

Comment: Actually passing `console.log` as callback, still works because is also a function, instead of creating extra function to handle to logs

Comment: Why should this not work? Asking this question, there's obviously *something* that you didn't fully understand about JS, but I can not tell what exactly this *something* is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you would pass the function `console.log` to the catch method. `console.log` method just prints each parameter in the console. Inside the catch method, the passed function will be executed on a reject/error of the promise.

Here is an example of passing functions:

```
function a(method) {
    method("Hello World");
}

a(console.log);
```

In this case, the `console.log` function is available as `method` in the `a` function as it has been passed as a parameter. This is the reason, the code prints `Hello World` in the console.

Answer (score -2):

Hidden arguments to sum it up here's an example!

```js
function test() {
    if (arguments[0] == "works") {
        console.log("COOL");
    }
}

test("works");
```

Comment: Also too, call-back function.